# Postgresql Explain analyse : time between nodes

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-performance

in a PostgreSQL explain plan like this one :

http://explain.depesz.com/s/wwO

What can justifie the time between the last hashjoin and hashaggregate ?

Only the volume of data to manipulate ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because of trimming the 2.9M rows down to 32.

Unrelated: Have you run ANALYZE on the tables referenced by that query? The estimates are pretty far off from the actual counts.

Comment: Thank you, so nothing to do about it ? ( or pre-aggregate data in my fact table...) all tables are analyzed, but at each join we dont lost any rows and postgresql considers that we will lost many rows each time.

Comment: We already needs to enable_nestloop = off for this type of request because of bad postgresql estimation.

Comment: I'm new to S.O. but in the pgsql-performance mailing lists (http://www.postgresql.org/list/) the usual suggestions are to report details as defined at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and to also post your query.